# Property for Array to be used inside List

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list

I have a `Class ABC`. And i want to write two properties for
it. One i have already mentioned in the code. The other one will be a `single dimensional array`.

```
Public Class ABC
    Private m_Type As String  
    Private SomeArray........need to write a property for array which will be of type `int`

    Public Property Type() As String
        Get
            Return m_Type
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_Type = value
        End Set
    End Property  

End Class
```

I am not sure how to define a property for array which can be used in a `List(Of ABC)`. The property for array can be a read only array as i will be

hard coding the data for it.

So basically when i do this,

```
Dim SomeList As New List(Of ABC)
```

And inside a for loop i need something like this,

```
SomeList.Item(index).SomeArray......this will give me all the items inside the array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare an array property the same way as you declare a different property type:

```
Public Class ABC
    Private _Type As String
    Private _SomeArray As Int32()

    Public Property SomeArray As Int32()
        Get
            Return _SomeArray
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int32())
            _SomeArray = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Type() As String
        Get
            Return _Type
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Type = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

for example, if you want to loop all `Integers` in one array of the list:

```
Dim index As Int32 = 0
Dim someList As New List(Of ABC) 
For Each i As Int32 In someList(index).SomeArray

Next
```

Comment: Actually i dont want it to be ReadOnly. I wont be able to add the values if its ReadOnly. I was trying to do something like this `someList.SomeArray= {1,2,3,4}` it didnt let me do it

Comment: @user2322507: Then don't make it `ReadOnly`. The only reason why i've made it read-only was because you've mentionded _"The property for array can be a read only array..."_.

Comment: yea and i realised i wont be able to add values later. can u please edit the answer.

Comment: i am trying to add data in the array property like this. `Dim SomeClass As New ABC` and then `SomeClass.SomeArray = {1,2,3,4}` But its not allowing me.

Comment: @user2322507: Edited my answer to show you how to remove the `ReadOnly` from the property. Now you can assign an array from outside of the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not going to be doing anything special in the Gets and Sets, you could simplify your code a little, as in the following (which initializes the read only array to contain the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4):

```
Public Class ABC
    Public Property Type As String  
    Public ReadOnly Property SomeArray As Integer() = {1,2,3,4}

End Class
```